# F-Bounded Polymorphic return types in Scala?

Tags: scala, generics, polymorphism

I'm going crazy trying to make F-Bounded Polymorphism work as I want in Scala.

The following code will not compile:

```
object TestTypeBounds {

   trait Upper[T <: Upper[T]] {
      def map() : T
   }

   class Impl extends Upper[Impl] {
      def map() : Impl = this
   }

  type Arr = Upper[T] forSome {type T <: Upper[T]}

  def testBounds() {

     // Though any is specified as the type parameter, the definition of Upper specifies
     // an upper bound of Upper
     val upper: Upper[_] = new Impl()

     // This must 'logically' be an Upper, but the compiler thinks it's an Any
     val mapped = upper.map()

     // This line will fail!
     mapped.map().map().map()
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
     testBounds()
  }
}
```

The problem here is that the compiler complains that the type of mapped is Any, and therefore it has no method map. It's not clear to me why the compiler does not assign mapped the type Upper since this is in fact the upper type bound of the parameter type of Upper, even if any was specified in this instance.

Note that replacing the type of "val upper...:" with the alias Arr would work, because now Scala can see that the type is recursive and will always be an Upper. Unfortunately, this approach does also not work for me because I am implementing a Java library which passes Upper[_] arguments to functions, and these then run into the above problem. The compiler also does not accept code where such functions are overridden as having "Arr" arguments, i.e. the alias does not work in that scenario.

**Edit: The final paragraph is not entirely correct, see my answer below**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Rado Buransky pointed out, you cannot just omit the type constructor parameter by using an underscore. The following works for example:

```
def testBounds[T <: Upper[T]](make: => T): Unit = {
  val upper: T = make
  val mapped = upper.map()
  mapped.map().map().map()
}

testBounds(new Impl)
```

Also this, using an existential type:

```
def testBounds: Unit = {
  val upper: Upper[T] forSome { type T <: Upper[T] } = new Impl
  val mapped = upper.map()
  mapped.map().map().map()
}
```

Comment: Thanks 0__, the existential type approach is indeed the Scala way of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

My view on this is that you should not use underscore "_". It tells the compiler that you don't care about the type parameter. But you do. I know that there is the upper bound, but probably there is an optimization which makes the compiler really don't care.

Just a hint, sometimes, for me, if nothing works, there is always the `asInstanceOf[T]` method. Maybe this helps you:

```
def giveMeUpper[T <: Upper[T]] = (new Impl).asInstanceOf[Upper[T]]
```

...

```
val upper = giveMeUpper[Impl]
```

Comment: I can't accept your first point. The underscore tells the compiler that I do not care to provide _any additional information_ on the type parameter, but the existing information, including the upper bound, should certainly be taken into account. Otherwise, a compiler optimisation is counteracting a language feature, and the upper bound becomes purely a restriction on which specific instances can be created, and which functions can be used within the implementation.

Comment: I understand your point and I am quite curious to hear some real explanation: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scala-language/OiFmOCV8pu8

Comment: Thanks for the effort on my behalf! I also qualify my earlier disagreement: I stand by my earlier assertion of what I am trying to say and therefore expect to happen, but you are correct in your assertion that the compiler takes it to mean that it can completely disregard this type (which in my opinion is not ideal behaviour).

Answer (score 0):

In terms of the 'pure' Scala part of the question, 0__ is correct and I have accepted his answer.

Regarding the Java Part: It turns out that if a Java function returns Upper and the Upper interface is defined in Java equivalently to the Scala implementation above, then the compiler does in fact correctly assign it the type Upper[_$2] forSome {type *$2 <: Upper[*$2]} - i.e. it interoperates correctly. The final problem I had was in fact caused by implicit functions defined in Scala that still returned Upper[_]. Mea Culpa.